# Which raspberry pi model for playing with electronics, maybe more?

Tags: hardware

Raspberry Pi beginner here. I've been looking at these beasts for a while. I'm very comfortable with programming and command line, but want to start playing around with electronics powered by software. By that I mean, physical hardware controlled by currents controlled by logic within the Pi.

I saw some interesting guides already that introduce in [controlling DC motors with a pi](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/controlling-dc-motors-using-python-with-a-raspberry-pi--cms-20051), for example. If I fork out for the Pi 2, will that be suitable? I don't mind it being overkill if it is, I'm likely to try many different things with it. Controlling a motor's rotations is simply the start.

Thanks guys!

Comment: I'd go for the Pi2.  It will let you do everything you want - just slightly faster! - and for the same price!

Comment: Whether the Pi 2 is actually the same price depends on who you order it from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using this for electronics you might as opt for a 40 pin model, i.e., A+/B+/2.  The only advantage the B+ has over the 2 is [very slightly lower power usage](http://raspi.tv/2015/raspberry-pi2-power-and-performance-measurement).  If power usage is a big concern and you don't need ethernet, etc., you could go for the A+.

Most people are going to want the Pi 2 here, however.  It is significantly faster, has twice as much RAM, and because of the more common architecture, can run a wider variety of operating systems.

Comment: Thanks @goldilocks and everyone else. Seems Pi2 is flexible enough to be the best fit. Let the experimenting begin!